# Makefile error when when compileing C code

Tags: c, shell, makefile

I downloaded the C source code for single-threaded Linux versions of cubist software. what the code does is it takes the input data and generates the regression tree model.

when compiling the source code using Ubuntu terminal it generated the Executable file with out error.
Here is the makefile

```
CC  = gcc -ffloat-store
OFLAGS = -O3
CFLAGS = -DVerbOpt -g -Wall -O0
LFLAGS = $(S)
SHELL  = /bin/csh
src =\
    global.c\
    xval.c\
    cubist.c\
    sort.c\
    construct.c\
    predict.c\
    stats.c\
    discr.c\
    rules.c\
    contin.c\
    formrules.c\
    formtree.c\
    getdata.c\
    getnames.c\
    implicitatt.c\
    instance.c\
    modelfiles.c\
    prunetree.c\
    regress.c\
    trees.c\
    update.c\
    utility.c

obj =\
     global.o cubist.o construct.o\
     formtree.o prunetree.o stats.o discr.o contin.o\
     trees.o\
     formrules.o rules.o\
     instance.o\
     predict.o\
     regress.o\
     xval.o\
     getnames.o getdata.o implicitatt.o sort.o\
     modelfiles.o\
     update.o utility.o\

all:
    make cubist
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OFLAGS) -o summary summary.c -lm


# debug version (including verbosity option)

cubistdbg:\
    $(obj) defns.i extern.i text.i Makefile
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o cubistdbg $(obj) -lm


# production version

cubist:\
    $(src) defns.i text.i Makefile
    cat defns.i $(src)\
        | egrep -v 'defns.i|extern.i' >cubistgt.c
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OFLAGS) -o cubist cubistgt.c -lm
    strip cubist
    rm cubistgt.c


$(obj):     Makefile defns.i extern.i text.i


.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

When i try to do similar work in windows i got error message

```
$ make all
make cubist
make: /bin/csh: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:56: all] Error 127
```

But when i try by removing SHELL  = /bin/csh from Makefile it worked. My question here is does it has negative effect on the software or 
how could i fix it with out removing SHELL  = /bin/csh.
thank you very much

Comment: So you say you downloaded Linux software and it doesn't work on windows? Am I getting this right?

Comment: What do you mean by "similar work". You're trying to use `make` in Windows shell against Linux source code? You do realize that if the source code is intended for Linux, it probably depends on something, maybe dozens of peculiarities of the system? Do you know what csh is? I am asking because I may be assesing the situation wrong. But I think you don't know anything about what you're doing.

Comment: I see no way `SHELL` setting in this specific example can influence anything.

Comment: @szpanczyk This seems to be a cli math program. Why shouldn't it run on Windows and Linux?

Comment: when i say similar work it is to mean" to compile make using CYGWIN in windows:::actually the make command in CYGWIN  created the executable but what i need to know is that removing SHELL = /bin/csh affects the source code??? frankly i don't know what csh mean.

Comment: @melaku /bin/csh is just one of many shells that exist for *nix. There's nothing in that Makefile that depends on it's particular style of shell scripting.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad why shouldn't? Well that depends on what mechanisms it relies. For primers we can see that the installation script relies on SHELL being set to /bin/csh. Doesn't sound like something that Windows can secure, right?

Comment: @melaku now that was crucial piece of information, that the executable was produced. I assumed it either did not, or did not work properly, because otherwise I don't see a reason to ask the question the way you did. But anyways, you've been answered so it's all ok I guess.

Comment: @szpanczyk This is easy to fix as others know. Obviously you didn't. However, this is no reason to write: *So you say you downloaded Linux software and it doesn't work on windows? Am I getting this right?*

Comment: @AminNegm-awad. no, it is just a c source code you can use for linux and with littel modification to windows

Comment: This is, what I said.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I do not wish to engage in meaningless emotional fights like the one you are provoking right now. If you need to scold people, go do it in the company you founded, you don't pay me so I don't have to deal with you.

Comment: @szpanczyk So why do you start "emotional fights"? I simply said, that this crazy idea of running linux SW on windows can be accomplished very easy in this case. Why do you feel emotions?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad You know that damn well. I'm done talking with you.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that by removing the line `SHELL = /bin/csh` your result is ok.

`/bin/csh` is a shell (command line interface, command processor, command prompt) used mostly in unix. In your makefile it is defined, but not referenced (not used).
Sometimes makefiles can need a shell (command processor) in order to execute some task, but it is up to the makefile - I mean, the person writing the makefile chooses to use that functionality or not and, if used, can (or must) specify which shell to use. This is not your case, now.